# JavaScript display duration

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm trying to make a little counter that display how much a movie has played, like on YouTube.

I want the time to output a  like this:

```
<div id="timeInfo">00:23</div>
```

How do I achieve this?
I tried the following without success:

```
function infTime (){
    timeInfo.innerHTML = formatTime(video.currentTime);

    if (video.duration) {
        timeInfo.innerHTML = formatTime(video.duration);
    }
}

function formatTime (seconds) {
    seconds = Math.round(seconds);

    minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    minutes = (minutes >= 10) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;

    seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
    seconds = (seconds >= 10) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;

    return minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

Comment: Other than the fact that "minutes" should be declared with the `var` keyword, that looks OK to me.  What about it was not successful? Oh wait I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is problematical:

```
seconds = Math.round(seconds);
```

You want to use `Math.floor` here to get the correct result.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/h6yst/

Comment: At worst that'd make it be off by a second, no?

Comment: @Pointy Using `Math.round` produces a result that is off by a half second (because the values [0.5, 1> result in '00:01' instead of '00:00', and the values [1.5, 2> result in '00:02' instead of '00:01', etc.). If you meant my demo, it's off by 100ms at worst.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the content by assigning to "innerHTML" twice.  The second expression could be written with "+=", or else (better) you could build the string separately:

```
infTime: function() {
  var info = formatTime(video.currentTime) + (video.duration ? ' ' + formatTime(video.duration) : '');
  timeInfo.innerHTML = info;
}
```

Now, of course that presumes that "timeInfo" is really a reference to the appropriate DOM element, obtained perhaps like this:

```
var timeInfo = document.getElementById('timeInfo');
```

Also, do remember to make "minutes" be a local variable by preceding its first use in the "formatTime" function with the `var` keyword:

```
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
```

Comment: Well, @Jeremy, don't you think that describing exactly what the problem is might help me provide assistance?

Comment: Don't confuse not wanting to describe the issue with not knowing how to describe it or even not knowing that a better description is needed `:)`

Comment: ha ha.  OK, well, @Jeremy, here are some guesses: is there a JavaScript error reported?  Does the time update but look incorrect?  Does the update not happen at all?  What sort of structure is this "infTime" function a part of, anyway?